# How many seasons are there of xxxHolic?

Tags: xxxholic

Are there more seasons of xxxHolic? The only seasons that I can find are 1 and 2 and I think 3.

Comment: Welcome to the Anime/Manga SE site. What exactly are you referring to with "more seasons"? Which have you see so far?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XxxHolic#Anime_TV_series

Comment: What country are you in and what language of the seasons are you talking about. in terms the English Release only the first season was ever released outside japan

Answer (score 3):

Ok, i am unsure what you mean by a 3rd Season but here's what i've looked up, there is

- [xxxHOLiC](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=6052) (Season 1) which was saw a number of releases outside Japan, 24 Episodes
- [xxxHOLiC: Kei](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=8551) (Season 2), this hasn't see as many releases, in the link there is a French Translator and Arabic Broadcaster but no licencing or distribution companies are listed, 13 Episodes
- [xxxHOLiC: Shunmuki](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=10583) (OVA), so far only dench is listed, 2 Episodes
- [xxxHOLiC: Rō](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=11396) (OVA), only in japan, 1 Episode
- [xxxHOLiC: Rō Adayume](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=12056) (OAV), once again only in japan, 1 Episode

there is also a xxxHOLiC movie called [xxxHOLiC the Movie: A Midsummer Night's Dream](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=4212), numerous releases and from what i've seen in Australia gets released with [Tsubasa RESERVoir CHRoNiCLE the Movie: The Princess in the Birdcage Kingdom](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=5148) aswell.

Finally, i should forget the [Manga](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/manga.php?id=2890) which is released in English.

the List above is i'm assuming the chronological order as the links all seem to indicate that much but i haven't seen the series myself however xxxHOLiC ties itself with Tsubasa RESERVoir CHRoNiCLE from my understanding.

To answer you main question **How many seasons are there of xxxHolic** i'd say only 2 Seasons and 4 OVA's (remember Shunmuki has 2 episodes)

Now i have no idea how long the OVA episodes go for however i accept Maria Watches Over Us OVA Season 3 is a season by itself as that has 4 episodes about 40-50 minutes each, in a sense that's about 8-10 regular episodes of a normal series or if xxxHOLiC's episodes OVA episodes are about that you can refer to them as seasons aswell

Comment: I only saw xxxholic and xxxholic Kei and one move